# Polymer Web Component Tester sendKeys

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

Is there a method that I can use to send keys to an input field using web component tester? I'd like to test sending the return key to a form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a method in Web Component Tester, but Polymer's [`iron-test-helpers`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-test-helpers) has `MockInteractions` that can [send keys to a target](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-test-helpers/blob/master/mock-interactions.js#L412). It even has one specifically for <kbd>ENTER</kbd>: [`MockInteractions.pressEnter(target)`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-test-helpers/blob/master/mock-interactions.js#L425).

#### Install

```
bower i --save-dev iron-test-helpers
```

#### Usage

```
<link rel="import" href="iron-test-helpers/iron-test-helpers.html">

<script>
  describe('accessibility', function(done) {
    it('should jump to next page on ENTER key', function() {
      var el = fixture('basic');
      var expectedIndex = el.pageIndex + 1;

      MockInteractions.pressEnter(el.$.nextBtn);

      // pressEnter() simulates key-down and asynchronous key-up,
      // so wait a while before testing the result
      setTimeout(function() {
        expect(el.pageIndex).to.be.eql(expectedIndex);
        done();
      }, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
```